# Find the nearest value of a list element

Tags: python, list, element, intersection

I have two lists which are:

```
>>> list1 = ['gain','archive','win','success']
>>> list2 = ['i','win','game','i','am','success','cool']
```

and also I found the same values of both list by comparing the lists.

```
>>> result= set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Output is

```
set(['win', 'success'])
```

Now I want to find the **next** element value of the `result`. Here it would be: `'game'` and `'cool'`.

How can I do this (using python 2.7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a pairwise iteration over your `list2` and do the "intersection" manually:

```
list1 = ['gain','archive','win','success']
list2 = ['i','win','game','i','am','success','cool']

set1 = set(list1)

result = []
for item, nextitem in zip(list2, list2[1:]):  # pairwise iteration
    if item in set1:
        result.append(nextitem)   # append the next item if the current item is in the intersection

print(result)  # ['game', 'cool']
```

Answer (score 7):

Given that you have the intersection words

```
result = { 'win', 'success' }
```

You could find the next words in `list2` like this:

```
next_words = [list2[list2.index(word)+1] for word in result]
```

[`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) gets you the index of the given element in the list. You can add 1 to it to get the next element.

If your element is at the *end* of the list, it will throw an exception, because there is no "next" element to get.

Comment: Nice, how can I avoid from  throw an exception when there is no "next" element.

Comment: Depends what you want to happen in that situation. You didn't specify.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `index` function and add 1. Be careful though, if your common element is the last one of your list, it will generate an error

```
list1 = ['gain','archive','win','success']
list2 = ['i','win','game','i','am','success','cool']
result= set(list1) & set(list2)

list3 = [list2[list2.index(e)+1] for e in result]
```

**edit** For the case where you last element is a common element:

```
result= set(list1) & set(list2)
list4 = []
for e in result:
    try:
        list4.append(list2[list2.index(e)+1])
    except:
        pass
```

Output: `['game', 'cool']`

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick for the next element in list2:

```
next_result = [list2[list2.index(el)+1] for el in result if list2.index(el)+1<len(list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `list2.index`, but that's doing a full search just for finding back an index, and artificially increasing complexity from `O(n)` to `O(n*n)`.

Just keep track of the indexes of each words.  There are several ways to do that.

- Create your own function that search for common words, and return them as the index of those words in `list2`.  This probably the least pythonic but the fastest.
- Create a dictionary from the words of `list2` to their index, then after computing the set intersection, lookup on the dict to find the index and increase by one.  You need to build a full dictionary the size of list2, this might be expensive (but still better than `O(n*n)`).
- Create a dictionary from the words of `list2` to their next word or `None` if there aren't and do a lookup on the dict to find the index.  You need to build a full dictionary the size of list2, this might be expensive.
- If you know how to use `itertools`, you could do an iterator on `list2` that yield the index and the word, and filter the result if the word is in `list1`, then pick only the indexes.